# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7ffeee917fb8)

Tags: ios, xcode, exc-bad-access, snapkit

I have a problem. Don't understand, why its happened. App crushes in the beggining because of that. You can see it on the screenshot. Please help! It's in SnapKit.ConstraintAttributes.

[EXC_BAD_ACCESS image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBiM3.png)

[Debugger outputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqTBW.png)

Comment: Can you please post the output from your debugger in regards to the crash?

Comment: Maybe you have `OS_ACTIVITY_MODE` enabled. Please disable it and post the debugger outputs again!